# Program to organize sewing patterns

Tags: windows, file-management

I am searching for an application that helps me to organize my sewing patterns (mostly pdf). For each file I want to

- assign some tags
- assign one (or more pictures). One specific picture
  should represent the whole sewing pattern on an overview page

Also I want to filter the sewing patterns by the tags and search for them.

Honestly I cannot phrase a google search that leads to any fitting results, so I am very thankful for any hint.

Comment: You might want to use web software for this.  (A private website.)

Answer (score 1):

I have recommended [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/) before for very different and varied purposes, it is a versatile note taking web application that could be used for many different tasks, including as a catalog for various types of data.

It works like a web page from a browser but can be used fully from a single local file. From there you can link to your PDF files and or images (ideally using relative paths to maintain portability).

Each tiddler (atomic unit of data) can be tagged, searched, filtered, and tailored to  present whatever data you like.

You can add custom fields for image files illustrating your patterns, and script it so they are listed as images or any other display form.

PDF files can be linked to as external files and embedded for direct display using the browser's builtin PDF plugin.

Comment: Very cool tool, thanks. But what is missing is an overview page with pictures for each element. Also these pictures should be shown in the search results.

Comment: That is relatively easy to achieve with some filters. You can easily builds templates and with some minor scripting a page that shows an overview with thumbnails, tags, titles and whatever other info you see fit for a complete or partialy filtered overview. I have done it before.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) E-Book Management software.

1. It handles pdf files just fine and a number of others
2. It can convert between a number of formats
3. You can assign an image as the cover photograph
4. You can assign and modify tags
5. You can filter on tags and much more.
6. It is free, gratis & open source
7. It is available for a number of platforms.

[image]